# How to attached calculation script to data-form in hyperion planning

Tags: dataform, hyperion, essbase

I am new to `Hyperion` going through small assignments.
I have created the data form in `Hyperion` planning it's working fine.
Now I have to attached `calc script` (calculation script) to my data form.
Is it possible to attach the `calc script` to data form ? How could I attach my `calc script` to `data form`?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach business rules to a form, which will let you run a calc from the form. Just create the business rule, then attach it to the form.

The documentation has a step-by-step process to do this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/hp_admin_11122/frameset.htm?rule_sel.html

Answer (score 0):

A couple years late... hope you already figured it out.

You need to differentiate calculation scripts and business rules first. For forms, you can only attach business rules to them.